# How to get out of grub error and stop it from happening again?

Tags: grub2, bootloader, windows-8, grubrescue

I have a Windows 8 laptop. I ran Ubuntu through a live USB and installed it (secure boot doesn't let WUBI otherwise).

When I used boot repair to boot back into Windows, it worked.
I restarted to go back to Ubuntu, but it showed this:

```
error: unknown filesystem. grub rescue>
```

No matter what I try from other threads I cannot go back to Windows 8 or Ubuntu. I even put the USB back in, but nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

#### Repairing grub with boot-repair

Put the your live USB stick back in and boot from it, but do not go the actual installation, but select the "Try Ubuntu" option. Then in the in the live session make sure you have internet connectivity, open terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install boot-repair
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
boot-repair
```

In **boot-repair**, select the "Recommended repair" option. After the repair finishes, reboot normally.